# Flexible Connection String

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This connection always fails when I transfer my system to another computer. Whatis the correct code for a connection string that can run on another computer?

```
Public Sub connect()

    con = New SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=true; User Id=sa;Password=sa;")
    con.Open()

End Sub
```

I'm expecting for the code that can be run on other PC when I transfer my system

Comment: What do you mean by **fail**?

Comment: what is the error message ? `transfer my system to another computer` And what is the setup on the other computer like ? local `SQLExpress` ?

Comment: After you fix this, don't leave your connections open like that.  Open, call your data, Close.

Comment: Is this a single user app where each user has there own database and there own installation of Sql Express? Or, are other user meant to connect to your computer and use a single database?

Comment: Im making a system that can backup a sql database to bak file and its perfectly working on my computer, but when i transfer my system to another the connection fails

Comment: Please show all relevant code.

Comment: Does the same database exist on the new computer? And does it have the same username/password? If not you can't have an "automatic" connection string which "automatically" connects to a local instance.

Answer (score 0):

That connection string will work on any machine that has a local instance of SQL Server Express with the default name.  There's no way to build a connection string that will magically work with any SQL Server instance with any name on any machine. If each user may need a different instance name then you have to provide for that.

One option is to store your connection string in the config file and let each user edit that by hand.  That's risky if your user's aren't technically inclined though.  You can also store the connection string attribute values somewhere, e.g. `My.Settings` and then provide a UI for the user to specify them at run time and persist them for later use.  The specifics of that are up to you but you can find an example here:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?532768

The point of that thread was the encryption part but you can ignore that and just use the rest.